# How to use a dynamically-determined Type as parameter to a Lambda<Func<>>?

Tags: dynamic, lambda, c#-3.0

I am dynamically creating a Lambda expression (based on user input but at the moment using dummy values for a proof-of-concept) for a type which I will only know at runtime.  I therefore need to pass the `T` portion of the `Func<T,TResult>` as a dynamic type, since I won't know the type until runtime (`TResult` will always be a `bool`).

It seems that I cannot pass in a `Type` variable or use `typeof` with generics.  Basically I'm trying to do something like this:

```
// (f => f.Baz == 1)
Type theType = Type.GetType("Foo");
ParameterExpression pe = Expression.Parameter(theType, "f");
Expression left = Expression.Property(pe, theType.GetProperty("Baz"));
Expression right = Expression.Constant(1);
Expression expr = Expression.Equal(left, right);
// This works fine but uses a hard-coded type, which I won't know until runtime:
// var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<Foo,bool>>(expr, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }).Compile();
var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<theType, bool>>(expr, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }).Compile();
```

However, I cannot use the variable `theType` as the `T` portion of the Func.  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't.

For example, in C#, you can't:

```
Type t = typeof(int);
List<t> list = new List<t>();
```

or

```
object list = new List<t>();
```

Unless you use reflection, but then you have to put the list in an `object`, and you can use it only through reflection.

So if you want you can save your `Func<>` in an `object` (or a `dynamic`) but nothing more.

What you COULD do is always return `Func<object, bool>` and cast the object to the desidered type IN the lambda function (so use a `Expression.Convert(pe, theType)`);

Or you could use the dynamic:

```
// lambda == Func<Foo, bool>
dynamic lamdba = Expression.Lambda(expr, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }).Compile();

bool res = lambda(myvalue);
```

or

```
// lambda == Func<Foo, bool>
Delegate lamdba = Expression.Lambda(expr, new ParameterExpression[] { pe }).Compile();
bool res = (bool)lambda2.DynamicInvoke(t);
```

To be taken "not as real" some benchmarks (in StopWatch.Ticks, look at them only for proportions) (Release Mode + Start Without Debugging + some useless cycles so that they are "hot"):

```
  236384685 dynamic
   56773593 Func<object, bool> + cast
10556024247 DynamicInvoke
```

as a note, `Func<Foo, bool>` has the same speed, so there isn't any speed lost in the extra cast.

You can see the code here http://ideone.com/qhnVP3